# How to open directory dialog in the client, in OpenERP7?

Tags: openerp-7

I have to generate files containing some data I retrieve from database. User must have the option to select where to save the generated files, but how to show the directory dialog in the client? I used Tkinter, but dialog apperared in the server (not in the client). Then I changed to python-wx library, and the result was the same.

I know OpenERP has a binary field, and you can select  a file from the client view, but I need to select a directory, not a file.

Please, how can I resolve this problem?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create fields.binary and put the data in this field (with base64). Then create a view to display this field and then, you can 'Save as' these data. When you click on the 'Save As' button, a directory dialog is opened on your client side to select the directory where you want to store your file.